# Detecting the iPhone Device is flat

Tags: iphone, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, orientation, accelerometer

To detect the orientation of the phone when taking a picture I use

```
orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight
orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown
orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait
orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft
```

But these work if the picture is being taken from the side. How do I check whether the iPhone is tilted downwards to be flat e.g. when taking an aerial picture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It exists other constant for the device orientation:

```
typedef enum {
   UIDeviceOrientationUnknown,
   UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,
   UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
   UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft,
   UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,
   UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp,
   UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown
} UIDeviceOrientation;
```

You can find them here: [UIDevice Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIDeviceOrientation)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `UIAccelerometer` (and `UIAccelerometerDelegate`) classes which must be used to detect device movements.
**Edit:** In UIAccelerometer class reference there're links to 3 related samples: [AccelorometerGraph](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/prerelease/library/samplecode/AccelerometerGraph/index.html), [GLGravity](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/prerelease/library/samplecode/GLGravity/Introduction/Intro.html) and [GLPaint](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/prerelease/library/samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

there's a sample app on http://developer.apple.com/iphone that graphs raw data from the accelerometer. Install it on your device, and have a look at the kind of data you get.

The sample app comes with an option (I think it's "damping") that effectively cancels out gravity. You don't want to do this - in fact gravity is what's going to "accelerate" your device in the Z axis when it's flat...